# set mat-select value by formcontrol without ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

may I set selected Value by formcontrol
i Have this snipped in my html document

```
  <!--segment panel-->
  <fa-expansion-panel class="expansion-panel-class" [title]="'Сегмент'">
    <mat-form-field
      floatLabel="always"
      class="segment-field fa-input-field full-width"
    >
      <mat-label>Обрані пункти</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControlName]="'segments'" multiple>
        <mat-option
          class="mat-options"
          *ngFor="let segment of segmentList"
          [value]="segment"
          >{{ segment.segName }}</mat-option
        >
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </fa-expansion-panel>
  <!--end segment panel-->
```

**in the ts file i have this form control**

```
segments = new FormControl()
```

**this is the segments list**

```
segmentList = [
 {id: 1, segName: 'hello'},
 {id: 2, segName: 'by'},
 {id: 3, segName: 'welcome'},
]
```

**here I'm changing the form control value**

```
segments.setValue([{id: 2, segName: 'by'}, {id: 3, segName: 'welcome'}])
```

the code compiles successfully, but no items are selected in the select box

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<mat-select [formControlName]="'segments'" multiple
       [compareWith]="compareObjects">
        <mat-option
          class="mat-options"
          *ngFor="let segment of segmentList"
          [value]="segment">
           {{ segment.segName }}
       </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

in the `ts` file define the `compareObjects` like:

```
compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
  return o1.segName === o2.segName && o1.id === o2.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with how Javascript handles objects. Let me explain.

Object in javascript are checked by reference. So let's say your `segmentList`

```
segmentList = [
 {id: 1, segName: 'hello'},
 {id: 2, segName: 'by'},
 {id: 3, segName: 'welcome'},
]
```

is equivalent to these references:

```
segmentList = [
  hash1abc,
  hash2edf,
  hash3ghi,
];
```

so when you select something, the formControl becomes equal to `hashxxx` reference, and it is shown by the value of `hash1abc.segName`.

If you follow me so far, you'll find the solution easily:

so when you do

```
segments.setValue([{id: 2, segName: 'by'}, {id: 3, segName: 'welcome'}])
```

you are doing:

```
segments.setValue([diffHashabc, diffHashcef])
```

your objects look the same, but they are indeed not the same ones that are on the list. So your mat-form does not recognize them. This happens because the array inside the `setValue` is a different set of Objects with different references.

I would try two things (unsure if these would solve the issue though), instead of writing them by hand, try getting them from your `segmentList` through `filter` or `find`.

Or try to use `trackBy: segmentFn` on your ngFor so it reads the id of the objects to know which one to render, instead of Object reference. Unsure if this would work but might. You would also need to add to the component `segmentFn = (index, segment) => segment.id;` for it to work

Answer (score 1):

You've created different objects, whereas Angular Material will compare by reference. Set the form by referencing the original objects:

```js
segments.setValue([this.segmentList[1], this.segmentList[2]])
```